# Android ListViews with custom adapters within LinearLayout - not scrolling correctly

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout that contains several text and button views, and two list views. These list views are populated dynamically with items - each item being a LinearLayout with a few TexViews, or a TextView and an ImageView.

Simplified version:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Example of a listview element that gets added to the above ListViews:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I would like to see is the full page to be scrollable. Not the individual elements within each ListView.

I've attempted the same thing with a TableLayout instead of a LinearLayout. I've tried many different approaches, with and without the scrollview, and one of the following keeps happening:

- The elements within each ListView become scrollable, while the whole page is *mostly* in place(some views get partially pushed off screen).
- Everything takes up all the space it needs to, but page is not scrollable and elements wind up off screen entirely.

Comment: You shouldn't put ListViews inside a ScrollView, try to get rid of the ListView and it should work better

Comment: Never put scrollable into scrollable, also ListView with height = wrap_content is nothing but a linearlayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put list views outside of scroll view. A list view will be scrolled if items in that list exceeds the screen size. Once you will put list views outside of scroll view then either of them will be scrolled individual.

Hope it solves your problem. Let me know.

Comment: I don't want the list views to be individually scrollable - just the entire screen(the scroll view). Another poster said that "ListView with height = wrap_content is nothing but a linearlayout" - but I can't set a custom adapter that extends arrayAdapter on a linearLayout. 

But once I figure out a workaround, I'll post my solution. This is a step in the right direction. I didn't know listViews were inherently scrollable and could not go into scrollViews.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to rethink my layout. I decided to go with two scrollable listviews. The key to having them not push things off screen was setting the layout height to 0dp and weight to 1 for each listview. (Of course you could set the weight to a different ratio, like 1 and 3, to have one take up more space than the other):

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/locationsListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/locationsListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```